# Form field input isn't received by JSON AJAX script

Tags: php, json, ajax, forms, file-upload

I am unable to catch the $productid from the form. Not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any ideas?

The selected files do upload, but not to the product folder specified, and nothing about the success is returned to index.php

It's strange but stackoverflow also mentions when trying to post "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details", but I have no more info to add?

Thanks

```
index.php

    <form method='post' action='' enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" id='productid' name="productid" value="<?=$productid?>">
    <input type="file" id='files' name="files[]" multiple><br>
    <input type="button" id='submitphotos' value='Upload'>

    <!-- Preview -->
    <div id='successupload'></div>
    <div id='preview'></div>
```

```
<script>

  $(document).ready(function(){

    $('#submitphotos').click(function(){

      var form_data = new FormData();

      // Read selected files
            var totalfiles = document.getElementById('files').files.length;
            var productid= $("#productid").val();
            for (var index = 0; index < totalfiles; index++) {
                form_data.append("files[]", document.getElementById('files').files[index]);
            }

            // AJAX request
            $.ajax({
                url: 'ajaxfile.php',
                type: 'post',
                data: form_data,
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                success: function (response) {

              for(var index = 0; index < response.length; index++) {
                  var src = response[index];

              // Add img element in <div id='preview'>
              $('#preview').append('<img src="'+src+'" width="400px;">');
              }

              $('#successupload').append('<h6>Successfully uploaded</h6><a href="back.php">back</a>');
              files.style.display = "none";
              submitphotos.style.display = "none";


                }
            });
    });
  });
```

```
ajaxfile.php

// Count total files
$countfiles = count($_FILES['files']['name']);

// Get product id
$productid = $_POST['productid'];

//Create request id folder if doesn't exist
if (!file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/images/products/'.$productid.'/')) {
        mkdir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/images/products/'.$productid.'/', 0777, true);
}

// Upload directory
$upload_location = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/images/products/".$productid."/";

// To store uploaded files path
$files_arr = array();

// Loop all files
for($index = 0;$index < $countfiles;$index++){

    if(isset($_FILES['files']['name'][$index]) && $_FILES['files']['name'][$index] != ''){

        // File name
        $filename = $_FILES['files']['name'][$index];

        // Get extension
        $ext = strtolower(pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

        // Valid image extension
        $valid_ext = array("png","jpeg","jpg","svg");

        // Check extension
        if(in_array($ext, $valid_ext)){

            // File path
            $path = $upload_location.$filename;

            // Upload file
            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$index],$path)){
                $files_arr[] = $path;
            }
        }
    }

}

echo json_encode($files_arr);
die;

</script>
```

Comment: Looks like you're not appending the product ID to the form data before sending it.

Comment: Thanks @TangentiallyPerpendicular, not sure how I would do that? I'm in a learning process

Comment: `form_data.append(...` perhaps? You're doing it for the files array two lines below.

Comment: Ok, thanks I have been trying to use a tutorial to understand this. I added:              form_data.append("productid", document.getElementById('productid');
But must still be doing something wrong..

Comment: form_data.append("productid", document.getElementById('productid').value);
This worked, but I'm not getting the #preview and #successupload to show afterwards though...

Answer (score 0):

You haven't passed the productid to the ajax call so just before ajax call add this:

```
form_data.append('productid', productid);
```

and your code should work fine.

Comment: Thanks, but this is the only one that worked for me. form_data.append("productid", document.getElementById('productid').value);